# Optaplanner - Real-time planning doesn't find good solution

Tags: optaplanner

I am trying to use real time planning using a custom SolverThread implementing SolverEventListener and the daemon mode.

I am not interested in inserting or deleting entities. I am just interested in "updating" them, for example, changing the "priority" for a particular entity in my PlanningEntityCollectionProperty collection.

At the moment, I am using:

```
scoreDirector.beforeProblemPropertyChanged(entity);
entity.setPriority(newPriority);
scoreDirector.afterProblemPropertyChanged(entity);
```

It seems that the solver is executed and it manages to improve the actual solution, but it only spends a few ms on it:

```
org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver: Real-time problem fact changes done: step total (1), new best score (0hard/-100medium/-15soft).
org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver: Solving restarted: time spent (152), best score (0hard/-100medium/-15soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE),
```

Therefore, the solver stops really soon, considering that my solver has a 10 seconds UnimprovedSecondsSpentLimit. So, the first time the solver is executed, it stops after 10 seconds, but the following times, it stops after a few ms and doesn't manage to get a good solution.

I am not sure I need to use "beforeProblemPropertyChanged" when the planning entity changes, but I can't find any alternative because "beforeVariableChanged" is used when the planning variable changes, right? Maybe optaplanner just doesn't support updates in the entities and I need to delete the old one using beforeEntityRemoved and inserted it again using beforeEntityAdded?

I was using BRANCH_AND_BOUND, however, I have changed to local search TABU_SEARCH and it seems that the scheduler uses 10 seconds now. However, it seems stuck in a local optima because it doesn't manage to improve the solution, even with a really small collection (10 entities).

Anyone with experience with real time planning?
Thanks

Comment: What do you see when you turn on DEBUG logging and remove the classname output from the log pattern?

Comment: The use of before/afterProblemPropertyChanged is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The "Solving restarted" always follows very shortly after "Real-time problem fact changes done", because real-time problem facts effectively "stop & restart" the solver. The 10 sec unimproved termination only starts counting again **after** the restart.

DEBUG logging (or even TRACE) will show you what's really going on.